# "UA_decodeBinary" is not able to decode the ExtensionObject

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

I am referring to  [Custom Data Types](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/tree/master/examples/custom_datatype).

My `Extension object` is not being decoded correctly. I have validated through Wireshark and also in Visual Studio debug mode (i.e. breakpoint on my `extension object`). The `Extension Object` receives the `byte String` correctly for my Custom Data Type. Its `"Content.Encoded"` field is being populated correctly (including the `DataType Field`) but the `"Content.Decoded"` field is not populated correctly .

I try to call the function  `"UA_decodeBinary"` -> It parses first two fields i.e. 1)Float 2)Boolean correctly but not the third field which is a String.

```
DataType Definition:

    enum nxNameSpace : UA_UInt16
    {
        eNXPNX = 4
    };

    enum nxDataTypes : UA_UInt32
    {
        eSMethodIdentifier = 5001,
        eSMethodBinaryEncodingID = 5002

    };

    typedef struct {
        UA_Float methodVersion;
        UA_Boolean generatesEvent;
        UA_String raisedEventName;
    } sMethod;


    static UA_DataTypeMember sMethod_members[3] = {
        {
            UA_TYPENAME("methodVersion") /* .memberName */
            & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_FLOAT],            /* .memberType */
            0,                                     /* .padding */
            false,                                 /* .isArray */
            false                                  /* .isOptional */
        },
        {
            UA_TYPENAME("generatesEvent")            /* .memberName */
            & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_BOOLEAN],             /* .memberType */
            0,                                     /* .padding */
            false,                                  /* .isArray */
            false                                  /* .isOptional */
        },
        {
            UA_TYPENAME("raisedEventName")            /* .memberName */
            & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING],             /* .memberType */
            0,                                     /* .padding */
            false,                                  /* .isArray */
            false                                  /* .isOptional */
        }
        
    };

    static  UA_DataType sMethodType = {
        UA_TYPENAME("sMethod")              /* .typeName */
        {eNXPNX, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {eSMethodIdentifier}},     /* .typeId */
        {eNXPNX, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {eSMethodBinaryEncodingID}}, /* .binaryEncodingId, the numeric
                                                identifier used on the wire (the
                                                namespaceindex is from .typeId) */
        sizeof(sMethod),                        /* .memSize */
        UA_DATATYPEKIND_STRUCTURE,              /* .typeKind */
        false,                                  /* .pointerFree */
        false,                                  /* .overlayable (depends on endianness and
                                                    the absence of padding) */
        3,                                      /* .membersSize */
        sMethod_members
    };
```

Calling from the main:

```
    UA_DataType type[5];
    type[0] = MyDataType;
    type[1] = sArgumentType;
    type[2] = sMethodType;
    type[3] = Point2DType;
    type[4] = Point3DType;

    UA_DataTypeArray customDataTypes = { NULL, 5, type };

    UA_Client* client = UA_Client_new();
    UA_ClientConfig* cc = UA_Client_getConfig(client);
    UA_ClientConfig_setDefault(cc);
    //cc->customDataTypes = &customDataTypes;
    
    
    UA_StatusCode retvalConnect = UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD;
    retvalConnect = UA_Client_connect(client, "opc.tcp://192.168.82.99:4840");
    if (retvalConnect != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD) {
        UA_Client_delete(client);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    UA_ReadRequest request;
    UA_ReadRequest_init(&request);
    UA_ReadValueId ids[5];
    
    UA_ReadRequest request;
    UA_ReadRequest_init(&request);
    UA_ReadValueId ids[1];
    UA_ReadValueId_init(&ids[0]);
    ids[0].attributeId = UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE;
    ids[0].nodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(4, (char*)"moveAbsolute");
    // set here the nodes you want to read
    request.nodesToRead = ids;
    request.nodesToReadSize = 1;
    
    UA_ReadResponse response = UA_Client_Service_read(client, request);
    UA_ExtensionObject* pK = reinterpret_cast<UA_ExtensionObject*>(response.results->value.data);
    
    sMethod myMethod;
    UA_ByteString bsmyMethod;
    bsmyMethod = pK->content.encoded.body;
    UA_StatusCode st = UA_decodeBinary(&bsmyMethod, &myMethod, &sMethodType, NULL);
    
    UA_Client_disconnect(client);
    UA_Client_delete(client);
```

I can see `"bsmyMethod "` byte string holding the data correctly from my external server and `"pk"` holding the correct data type info i.e.
`"eSMethodIdentifier = 5001 & eSMethodBinaryEncodingID = 5002"`. But `"UA_decodeBinary"` -> It parses first two fields i.e. 1)Float 2)Boolean correctly but not the third field which is a String.

Another weird thing is that when I uncomment `"//cc->customDataTypes = &customDataTypes;"` line , it is throwing exception at `"UA_ReadRequest_init(&request);"`. and sometimes `"BadServiceRequest"`.

I have tried everything now and not able to figure out why my Data Type is not parsed correctly. Can someone please help?

Version: open62541-1.3 .I downloaded the source file and compiled with Visual Studio 2019 using CMAKE GUI.